# How do I create many-to-many association using Flask-sqlalchemy with extra data?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to associate two models **employee** and **skill** using flask-sqlalchemy with extra data.

For example, **user1** can do **skill1** with efficiency 100% and **skill2** with efficiency 80%.

So, I make 3 models:

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'employees'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)

    skills = db.relationship('Skill', secondary='employee_skills',
                             backref=db.backref('employees', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Employee %r, Skills: %r>' % (self.login, self.skills)


class Skill(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'skills'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Skill %r>' % self.name


class EmployeeSkill(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'employee_skills'

    employee_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('employees.id'), primary_key=True)
    skill_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('skills.id'), primary_key=True)
    efficiency = db.Column(db.Float)

    skills_efficiency = db.relationship('Skill', backref=db.backref('employee_efficiency', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Engineer %r, skill %r, efficiency %r>' % (
            self.employee_id, self.skill_id, self.efficiency)
```

After that I try to access to this associantion:

```
>>> from app import db, models      
>>> emp_=models.Employee.query.all()
>>> emp_[0]
<Employee u'user1', Skills: [<Skill u'skill1'>, <Skill u'skill2'>]>
>>> emp_[0].skills
[<Skill u'skill1'>, <Skill u'skill2'>]
>>> emp_[0].skills[0]
<Skill u'skill1'>
>>> emp_[0].skills[0].employee_efficiency
<sqlalchemy.orm.dynamic.AppenderBaseQuery object at 0x0000000003A68FD0>
>>> emp_[0].skills[0].employee_efficiency[0]
<Engineer 1, skill 1, efficiency u'1'>
```

What I want is to represent **Employee** instance as

```
<Employee u'user1', Skills: <u'skill1', efficiency: '1'>, <u'skill2', efficiency: '0.8'>>
```

But I don't understand: Do I use db.relationship in a wrong way? Or do I need to complite my **repr** method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you need extra columns in the association table you need to use the [association object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#association-pattern) pattern instead of the `secondary` attribute. This pattern basically consists in decomposing the many-to-many relationship into two one-to-many relationships.

In your case you would create a one-to-many relationship from `Employee` to `EmployeeSkills`, and you would keep the many-to-one relationship you already have between `EmployeeSkills` and `Skill`.

When you use the `secondary` attribute SQLAlchemy manages the association table automatically for you. When you use the association object pattern you have to manage the association table yourself, and that gives you access to set or query the extra columns.

Comment: Indeed, read the *Note* in the section of the documentation @Miguel linked to. It is suggested for you to get rid of the many-to-many relationship definition.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you could change the `repr` method:

```
class Skill(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'skills'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Skill %r, efficiency: %r>' % (self.name, self.employee_efficiency[0].efficiency)
```

You already have the backref, so use that.